# Unable to get TIME_FORMAT to show 24-hour time

Tags: mysql

Using mySQL 5.6.

I am storing time in my database like this:

```
15:00:00
```

(So that's 3:00 pm.  This is what is stored in the database.)

When I want to select data based on time, I do something like this:

```
@x = "03:00 pm";     (This is what is being passed in from my time widget.)

SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE start = TIME_FORMAT(@x, '%H:%i:%s');
```

But this returns 03:00:00, so no match.
(Remember 15:00:00 is in the database, so I need TIME_FORMAT to change 3:00 pm to 15:00:00, not 03:00:00.)

I have tried all of the following:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('03:00 pm', '%H:%i:%s')
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('03:00 pm', '%h:%i:%s')
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('03:00 pm', '%T')
```

And NONE of them give me the 15:00:00 that I need.

Here is what the manual says:

```
This is used like the DATE_FORMAT() function, but the format string may
contain format specifiers only for hours, minutes, seconds, and microseconds.
Other specifiers produce a NULL value or 0.
```

And here are a number of sites showing examples and the tables that show what formatting symbols will work with the TIME_FORMAT function:

```
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/time_format.php
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/TIMEFORMATtimeformat.htm
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time_format-function.php
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-time/
```

So, everything here is telling me that what I'm doing should work.

What am I not getting here?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent, you start by saying you're storing time as a 24 hour value, but then your asking at the end why none of the methods used are returing a 24 hour format?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)?

Comment: So I have clarified my issue.  And yes, Martin, I have read the manual.  And searched everywhere I could think.  But I work alone, at home, and sometime I just need another pair of eyes to point me in the right direction.  Don't be snarky.

Comment: I was not being "snarky". We only know as much as you can tell us, so if you don't tell us you've read the manual, we can't assume you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

```
select str_to_date('03:00 pm','%h:%i %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('03:00 pm', '%H:%i:%s')
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('03:00 pm', '%H:%i:%S')
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('03:00 pm', '%T')
```

are correct to storing your database like your wanting.
maybe you should try to change the 'date' parameter.